# Segue to controller takes 5-10 seconds to display

Tags: ios, swift, camera, segue, avcapturesession

I am using swift 4 and have an app where people can open their phone camera through my app. I have a ViewController called `CameraController` which has the default `UIView` and I have a view on top of that called `CameraView` which displays the users camera and other buttons on top of that.

When I clicked one of those buttons it takes me to another view controller via a segue (`PlacesController`). When I dismiss the `PlacesController` I go back to the `CameraController` however the subview now takes about 8 or 10 seconds to display again.

Is there someway that I can go to another **Controller** while maintaining my current subview?

Again the issue is that when I go to my segue controller `PlaceController` and then go back to my `CameraController` it takes about 8 or 10 seconds before the camera and sublayer become visible. Specifically this code below and I was wondering if I could keep my sublayer still running since waiting 10 seconds for it to show is too much.

```
self.CameraView.layer.insertSublayer(previewLayer!, at: 0)
```

This is my code:

```
class CameraController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var CameraView: UIView!
     var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
     let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()


  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    }
 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
           DispatchQueue.main.async {
             self.beginSession()
        }

    func beginSession() {
   // gets the camera showing and displays buttons on top of it
        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        self.CameraView.layer.insertSublayer(previewLayer!, at: 0)
        previewLayer?.frame = self.CameraView.layer.bounds

        previewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        captureSession.startRunning()
        stillImageOutput.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.jpeg]
        if captureSession.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput) {
            captureSession.addOutput(stillImageOutput)
        }
    }


  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "PlacesController" {
            let PlaceAreaSearchC: ColorC = segue.destination as! PlacesController
            PlaceAreaSearchC.delegate = self
        }
    }

 // PlacesController
class PlacesController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func backAction(_ sender: Any) {
   // This is how I go back to my view CameraController
         dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
 }
```

Comment: Use Instruments to try to narrow down your problem.

Comment: How about using a different thread for your beginSession?  What you're doing now is running it on the main GUI thread (... all you've done with your current IMPL is just move it to the end of the main queue, but it's still on the GUI's queue).  What happens if you try this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `AVCaptureSession` `startRunning` call is blocking your main thread thus the delay.

As it says in [`startRunning()`’s Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturesession/1388185-startrunning):

> The startRunning() method is a blocking call which can take some time,
>   therefore you should perform session setup on a serial queue so that
>   the main queue isn't blocked (which keeps the UI responsive).

Comment: It would be great to see working code example wrapping that call in something other than the main thread, that would make this answer canonical.

Comment: @DimaTisnek check out my answer below

Answer (score 9):

In addition to [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50780105/2385538) of **Lyndsey Scott**:

```
    let backCamera: AVCaptureDevice? = AVCaptureDevice.default(AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: AVMediaType.video, position: AVCaptureDevice.Position.back)

    guard let camera = backCamera, let deviceInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: camera) else {
        self?.didReceive(captureSession: nil)
        return
    }

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async { [weak self] in
        let deviceOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
        let cameraSession = AVCaptureSession()

        cameraSession.beginConfiguration()
        cameraSession.sessionPreset = .low
        if cameraSession.canAddInput(deviceInput) {
            cameraSession.addInput(deviceInput)
        }
        if cameraSession.canAddOutput(deviceOutput) {
            cameraSession.addOutput(deviceOutput)
        }
        cameraSession.commitConfiguration()
        cameraSession.startRunning()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self?.didReceive(captureSession: cameraSession)
        }
    }
```

> Xcode 10.0, Swift 4.2